# How to format display text in mvc page using razor DisplayFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on asp.net mvc3 application.

In this user can post data, i am using textarea for input. This data is stored into database and i am retrieving it using razor @Html.DisplayFor().

My Data for textarea is like this (inputed by user)

```
Oh woooah, oh woooooah, oh wooooah, oh.
You know you love me, I know you care,
you shout whenever and I’ll be there.
You are my love, you are my heart
and we will never ever ever be apart.
Are we an item? girl quit playing,
we’re just friends, what are you saying.
Said there’s another, look right in my eyes,
my first love broke my heart for the first time.
And I was like…


Baby, baby, baby oooooh,
like baby, baby, baby noooooooo,
like baby, baby, baby, ooooh.
Thought you’d always be mine, mine (repeat)
```

and when i retrieve it using this,

```
<em>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.inputvalue)</em>
```

but it is displayed as unformated text like below,

Oh woooah, oh woooooah, oh wooooah, oh. You know you love me, I know you care, you shout whenever and I’ll be there. You are my love, you are my heart and we will never ever ever be apart. Are we an item? girl quit playing, we’re just friends, what are you saying. Said there’s another, look right in my eyes, my first love broke my heart for the first time. And I was like… Baby, baby, baby oooooh, like baby, baby, baby noooooooo, like baby, baby, baby, ooooh. Thought you’d always be mine, mine (repeat)

How can i format display text?
Is there any property to display this as formated text?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made few changes in [Darin Dimitrov's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) answer. Its now working perfect..

Thanks [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) for your help.

```
public static class HtmlExtensions

    {
        public static IHtmlString DisplayFormattedData(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string data)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
            }

            string myString=data;
                myString = myString.Replace("\n", "<br>");

                return new HtmlString(myString);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You should replace new lines with `<br/>`. You could write a custom helper to do this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString DisplayFormattedData(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var result = string.Join(
            "<br/>", 
            data
                .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Select(htmlHelper.Encode)
        );
        return new HtmlString(result);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.DisplayFormattedData(item.inputvalue)
```

Comment: its showing me 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MySolution.Web.Models.UserModel>>' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFormattedData' and no extension method 'DisplayFormattedData' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MySolution.Web.Models.UserModel>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) What can i do to resolve this?

Comment: @Bhargav It is stated on the error message: **(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**. Reference your namespace on the web.config inside your views folder or on the page itself.

Comment: @tugberk: I have created one folder named MvcHtmlHelpers. In that i have created class as above. and my namespace for this is: namespace MySolution.Web.MvcHtmlHelpers. I have included this in web.config as <add namespace="MySolution.Web.MvcHtmlHelpers"/> but its not working. :( whats the issue?

Comment: @Bhargav, if you are using Razor it is not in `~/web.config` that you should include this namespace. It is inside `~/Views/web.config`. Once you do that don't forget to close and reopen the Razor view as Visual Studio doesn't pick changes automatically.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: using  DisplayFormattedData both string data and result having same data. Output is not as per we expect. I am trying to figure it out but cant find. Whts the problem?